# What type of conditional is this?

Tags: conditionals

I know about conditional sentences type 2, but I want to know in which category this kind of conditional sentence is placed:

> If I could go anywhere in the world, I would travel to the U.S.

Answer (score -1):

This sentence is an example of Conditional sentences with **Modal Verbs**.

A **modal verb** (also modal, modal auxiliary verb, or modal auxiliary) is a type of verb that is used to indicate modality – that is, likelihood, ability, permission, and obligation.

Examples include the English verbs **can/could**, **may/might**, **must**, **will/would**, and **shall/should**.

Example-If he **could** help, he **would**.

Refer to [this](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/conditional_sentences08.html) site for more information regarding this topic.

Comment: The Wikipedia quote needs to be attributed, or you will be committing a copyright infringement.